# multiple conditions in switch C#

Tags: c#

Unable to add multiple conditions in switch statement. 
How to do this using a switch statement? do i have to use multiple if conditions?

```
string oldValue = ".....long string1....";
string newValue = ".....long string2....";
switch (oldValue.Length && newValue.Length)
{
    case <500 && <500:
        //insert as is
        break;
    case >500 && <500:
        //split oldValue into array of strings and insert each
        //insert newValue as is
        break;
    case <500 && >500:
        //insert oldValue As is
        //split newValue into array of strings and insert each
        break;
    case >500 && >500:
        //split oldValue into array of strings and insert each
        //split newValue into array of strings and insert each
        break;
    default:
        break;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looking at your comments, the length of `oldValue` only affects what you do with `oldValue`, and the length of `newValue` only affects what you do with `newValue`.

Why not split this into two separate statements? Or even into a common method?

```
string[] GetValuesToInsert(String input)
{
    if (input.Length < 500)
        return new[] {input};
    else
        return input.Split(...);
}

whatever.Insert(GetValuesToInsert(oldValue));
whatever.Insert(GetValuesToInsert(newValue));
```

Answer (score 5):

No, you can't do this. `switch` statements test against values, not expressions.

You need to use `if` statements instead.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot do this, you need to use `if` and `else if`.

`switch` typically uses a different technique to jump to the right branch (called jumptable). Basically it is a single jump whose target location is computed out of the `value` of `switch(value)`, not a number of sequentials comparisions. Details depend on the architecture.

Answer (score 0):

Simply you are breaking switch statement rules. You can not pass expression there.
You need to pass a value. Please refer the following link
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/06tc147t(v=vs.71).aspx

You need to use if-else statement.